# Delete all in Debug log

Tags: debug

**Delete all** option in Debug log *deletes the log page-wise*. Is there any option to delete all the logs in debug at an instance?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`SELECt ID from APEXLOG` and run this query in **DC Query Editior** and select the `tooling API` checkbox. 
Now Delete all the records. It will solve your problem and this is a native solution.

Comment: DC = Developer Console on the username drop down for those that are confused

Comment: did not work for me, instead I got many alerts telling "invalid cross reference id". Any idea what could be going wrong?

Comment: That's only because when the exact row is getting deleted in the backend, the query result is not refreshed. So you might have selected the row again and clicked to delete, causing the alerts telling "invalid cross reference id".

Answer (score 54):

Now that we have SFDX, I use the below method to delete debug logs from terminal:

```
$ sfdx force:data:soql:query -t -q "SELECT Id FROM ApexLog" -r "csv" > out.csv
$ sfdx force:data:bulk:delete -s ApexLog -f out.csv
```

Here is **sf** version of it:

```
echo "Id" > temp.csv; \
sf apex list log --json | jq -r '.result[].Id' >> temp.csv && \
sf data delete bulk --sobject ApexLog --file temp.csv --wait 1000
```

Comment: Amazing, worked like a charm. Long live Salesforce DX!

Comment: Better than every option on here.

Comment: Why it continuously says InvalidBatch : Records not found when I check the status?

Comment: @AdityaVijay  when you run check status command, it might be running against different org. Make sure to pass —targetusername argument

Comment: @javanoob i am getting error taking this approach. After starting delete job i check for job status and i get:

`stateMessage: InvalidBatch : Records not found`

Any idea why this is happening? Btw. this would be the cleanest solution i've seen so far. Thanks!

Comment: For Windows users that struggle with this solution - PowerShell creates files in utf16-le that Salesforce bulk API doesn't understand. I use this instead:
`sfdx force:data:soql:query -q "SELECT Id FROM ApexLog" -r "csv" | out-file -encoding utf8 out.csv`

Comment: @Artur this gives the file encoding as utf8-bom, not utf8, which still says invalid batch. I tried to find downloading the file as utf8 but I didn't get any. I added an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/63900678/1298013

Comment: I hit the "InvalidBatch : Records not found" error too.  The "output in UTF8" solution got close, then I loaded the file in vim, ran ":set nobomb" and saved it, and now I had a clean UTF8 file to use, which worked.

Comment: @AdityaVijay I started having inconsistent results myself which depend on the context. Anyway, `-encoding ascii` did the trick.

Comment: Followed steps and finally got "Bulk Delete... done" message in command line. But nothing got deleted. Any idea why? btw I am pointing to correct org.

Comment: This would make a perfect candidate for a [VSCode Task](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks)

Comment: Worked great! Note that as of this writing I cannot do SELECT Id FROM ApexLog in developer console query window anymore, even with tooling api checkbox checked.

Answer (score 14):

I had an org with over 400mb of logs that needed to be cleared! The Salesforce developer tools only lets you delete 2000 rows at a time and the process has to be manually repeated.

So instead I opened up Salesforce classic debug log page and run the following JavaScript from Chrome Developer Tools - it will keep bashing the *Delete All* button for you.

```
setInterval(
    function() {
       if (document.querySelector('span[id*="deleteAllStatus.start"]').style.display === 'none') {document.querySelector('input[value="Delete All"]').click()}
    }
    ,250);
```

Comment: Please check my answer, doing the same but in a more optimized way :-)

Answer (score 12):

Use apex debugger chrome extensions. There you can select debug size. for example select 5000 and delete all the debugs. Great tool

### Chrome extensions

### **[Apex Debugger](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/apex-debugger/mpckkbblhbfngaininanfjpdfjhbncjo?hl=en)**

### **[Salesforce Coding Utility](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/salesforce-coding-utility/noiijdfibmplbakepjmedfjhfdmghbgf?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon)**

Comment: there seems to be a firefox version now as well: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/100401/delete-all-in-debug-log

Answer (score 6):

I used the dataloader to export and delete all the debug logs. There were over 4K records so this was without a doubt the quickest way to do it. I chose the object ApexLog and used the following query:

```
SELECT Id, Status, StartTime, LogUser.Name, Operation, DurationMilliseconds, Location, LogLength, Application FROM ApexLog
```

Answer (score 5):

Cross Posting as this question seems more canonical.

You cannot delete the debug logs natively in Apex code. But you can use Rest DELETE endpoint to delete debug logs.

I have created a utility code to delete debug logs that way, you can refer it.

The only limitation is

1. It can delete only 100 in 1 iteration(You can use composite API to
   bulkify it).
2. It creates a new debug log after execution

   ```
    List <Apexlog> loglist = [Select Id from Apexlog limit 100];
   for(Apexlog al: loglist){
       Http h = new Http();
       HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
       req.setEndpoint(Url.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm()
       + '/services/data/v44.0/sobjects/Apexlog/'+al.Id);
       req.setMethod('DELETE');
       req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
       HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
       System.debug(res.getStatusCode());
   }
   ```

If you are calling this method from the lightning component, your Session ID wont be api enabled. Thus you have to use named credentials.

src: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/239642/19118

Answer (score 5):

In workbench, query for apex log using below query:

1. **SELECT Id FROM ApexLog**
2. Select view as: Bulk CSV
3. Download the csv file
4. Then in workbench go to
5. Data tab -> select delete option
6. select From file check box
7. upload the csv file you got from above mentioned query.
8. Click on next
9. click on map fields (id)
10. click the check box:
11. Process records asynchronously via Bulk API
12. Verify that the object type is: ApexLog
13. Click on confirm delete.

Answer (score 3):

There is an extension in Google Chrome called the **salesforce-tool** which helps in deleting all the logs at once. You won't have to click **Delete All** everytime. It has some other functionalities too.

Answer (score 2):

I've had success using the Bulk API to rapidly remove the existing ApexLog records.

Steps (that are automated):

1. Use SOQL to Query all the ApexLog records and get back the Ids
   `Select Id from Apexlog`
2. If there are few records, currently less than 400, delete them with one or two calls the the Partner API.
3. Otherwise, with many records, use the Bulk API to delete them by Id.

I needed to automate this as I'd occasionally come across production orgs with tens of thousands of records that needed to be deleted before a new TraceFlag could be created.

[image]

This functionality is available (on Windows) in the FuseIT SFDC Explorer. See 
[Button to delete ALL ApexLog's in an org.](http://www.fishofprey.com/2018/07/fuseit-sfdc-explorer-39181901-summer-18.html#deleteAllLogs)

Answer (score 2):

Open the browser console and execute this

```
(function() {
    var request = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function() {
        this.addEventListener('load', function() {
        if(document.querySelector('[id$="thetracetable"] tbody tr')){
             document.querySelectorAll('[id$="deleteAll"]')[0].click();
        }
    });
    request.apply(this, arguments);
};
})();
document.querySelectorAll('[id$="deleteAll"]')[0].click();
```

Answer (score 0):

From my side When getting this error in console. I tried via dataloader and it works. I extract all the log and from the same csv I execute the delete.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [sfdx-hardis](https://github.com/hardisgroupcom/sfdx-hardis#sfdx-hardisorgpurgeapexlog--z--d---websocket-string--u-string---apiversion-string---json---loglevel-tracedebuginfowarnerrorfataltracedebuginfowarnerrorfatal) command to delete all logs of an org

```
sfdx hardis:org:purge:apexlog
```

If you are not connected to an org, it will prompt you for one

This command is also available in [VsCode SFDX Hardis](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=NicolasVuillamy.vscode-sfdx-hardis) menu **Debugger**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The option for deleting all debug logs I've been using for years and it works perfectly is a Chrome Extension that provides a button called 'Truly, Delete All' on the Setup debug logs page.

It unfortunately works only in classic interface, so if that's not a deal breaker I highly recommend it.

The chrome extension is called: **Salesforce advanced Code Searcher**.

Answer (score -1):

You can try with salesforce inspector tool

Comment: What is this tool? How would you use it to acccomplish this task? Is this perhaps covered by an existing answer? Being detailed in answers is important.