# How to Delete All Debug Apex logs in Apex?

Tags: apex, debug-logs

I'm trying to delete the complete Apex debug logs but getting DML operation Delete not allowed on `List<ApexLog>`.

Code:

```
List <Apexlog> loglist = [Select Id from Apexlog];
delete loglist;
```

Please provide an idea to delete complete debug logs in code.

Answer (score 21):

You cannot delete the debug logs natively in Apex code. But you can use Rest DELETE endpoint to delete debug logs.

I have created a utility code to delete debug logs that way, you can refer it.

The only limitation is

1. It can delete only 100 in 1 iteration(You can use composite API to bulkify it)
2. It creates a new debug log after execution

   ```
   List <Apexlog> loglist = [Select Id from Apexlog limit 100];
   for(Apexlog al: loglist){
       Http h = new Http();
       HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
       req.setEndpoint(Url.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm()
       + '/services/data/v44.0/sobjects/Apexlog/'+al.Id);
       req.setMethod('DELETE');
       req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());
       HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
       System.debug(res.getStatusCode());
   }

   System.debug('loglist'+loglist);
   ```

If you are calling this method from lightning component, your Session ID wont be api enabled. Thus you have to use named credentials .

Src: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/183692/19118

Comment: Nice, that is a useful bit of code.

Comment: Yeah, its quite handy when your org creates 100'smb of debug log a minute.

Comment: Nice Solution! Note that this works only if you're not in a Lightning context, since Lightning Session IDs would not be API-enabled.

Comment: Yups, in lightning, one needs to use Named credentials. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/183692/19118

Comment: May be worth adding this answer to the question flagged as duplicate, as that one seems more canonical given viewership, age, number of answers, etc.

Comment: Best part is that this runs in developer console execute anonymous!!!

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell, the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_apexlog.htm) is mistaken in showing that `ApexLog` can be deleted from Apex DML.

The object is deletable from the [Tooling API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_apexlog.htm), however. You can tackle this in two ways:

1. You can actually call out to the Tooling API from your Apex code to perform a delete operation on the object. You would make a `DELETE` method callout to the REST endpoint

   > /services/data/v43.0/tooling/sobjects/ApexLog/YOUR_LOG_ID
2. You can do it directly from the Developer Console, without writing a line of code. Simply write `SELECT Id FROM ApexLog` in the Query Editor, check "Use Tooling API", and execute the query. Then, select rows in the results display, and click the Delete Rows button to remove them.

Comment: May be worth adding this answer to the question flagged as duplicate, as that one seems more canonical given viewership, age, number of answers, etc.

Comment: We don't actually have to check "Use Tooling API" checkbox to be able to delete the ApexLog record from the Query Editor tab.