# Mass delete Debug logs using Developer Console: Invalid cross-reference id

Tags: developer-console, debug-logs

**Given**

- warning in Developer Console that Debug Logs exceeded limit and some must be deleted in order to set new trace flags
- execute in DC (via Tooling API option in Query Editor) `Select Id from ApexLog`

**When returned rows mass-selected and Delete Rows option clicked**

**Then**

- Sometimes, the DC returns with 1+ popup dialog `INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_ID [object Object] : Invalid cross reference id`

The only lookup field on ApexLog is `LogUserId` and I could see that every ApexLog I was deleting shared the same `LogUserId`.  Every entry being deleted was a Location `SystemLog` w/ Operation `SerialBatchApexRangeChunkHandler`

Now I know there are [many alternative ways of deleting these logs](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/100401/delete-all-in-debug-log) but what would cause these sporadic INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_ID errors?  They could occur whether I deleted 200, 400, or 600 rows at once - each DC bulk deletion might surface 1..12 popup dialogs with no apparent correlation to what I was doing.

> Hypothesis 1 - The LogUserId happens to be a user that is concurrently
>   running other batch jobs while I'm trying to clean up logs from
>   previous batch jobs. Some contention occurs during the DC bulk delete
>
> Hypothesis 2 - DC itself is having challenges refreshing the results
>   pane during the bulk deletion and these INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_ID
>   refers to objects used by DC itself.

Comment: I've noticed several species of weird behavior from Developer Console when interacting with log files in high volume. I've seen that requests to delete large volumes of log files often seem to delete an order of magnitude fewer logs than expected, making me wonder if Console is running batch deletes *really slowly* and getting into race conditions with itself.

Comment: @DavidReed - I limited myself to deletions in batches of <= 600 and did not notice any `delete an order of magnitude fewer logs than expected`. But clearly based on your observations and mine, something is going on

Comment: I was requesting deletes in batches of 2,000 and seeing only ~400 or so actually being deleted. I also saw the error you mention, although not in the volume you experienced.

Comment: @DavidReed : I gave up on trying 2,000 as DC+Chrome would just hang; hence < 600

Comment: I'd try and capture the underlying Tooling API delete operation that the developer console is performing when the error occurs. I've been bulk deleting the ApexLog records, sometimes in the tens of thousands, and haven't run into the same issue yet. That said, I wasn't using the Developer Console to do it either.

Comment: fwiw the dev console seems to do one delete at a time when you select multiple records from a query result, you can see this in action pretty easily, just more than a couple hundred rows and then refresh the query repeatedly, you'll see the number slowly tick down.